# angular-in-memory-web-api for query params other than object attributes

Tags: angular, http, angular-http

I have a collection of book objects in memory,

```
book { title: string, author: string, description: string }
```

Now the url for searching book is

```
api/books/search/{text}
```

the real web api does check for matches in all attributes of books including author, title and description.

In the angular-in-memory-web-api I can have urls like,

```
api/books/?title={text}
api/books/?author={text}
```

etc.

Is there any way to have *api/books/search/{text}* this url working with the angular-in-memory-web-api?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, but I think you've to override the parseRequestUrl method in your data service.

Example:

```
parseRequestUrl(url: string, utils: RequestInfoUtilities): ParsedRequestUrl {
  const newUrl = url.replace('/books/search/', '/books/?title=');
  const parsed = utils.parseRequestUrl(newUrl);
  return parsed;
}
```